# Where do `@numba.jitclass`ed special methods go?

Tags: python, numba

TL;DR: When decorating a class with [`@numba.jitclass`](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.27.0/user/jitclass.html) special methods such as `__add__` do not appear in instances of the class, while other methods work normally. Why does this happen?

Consider the following class declaration:

```
import numba as nb            

dual_spec = [('x', nb.float64), ('y', nb.float64)]                 

@nb.jitclass(dual_spec)
class xy:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def addition(self, other):
        return xy(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return xy(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

Without the decorator the class works perfectly fine. Due to the `__add__` method expressions like `xy(1, 2) + xy(3, 4)` are possible and return expected results. However, with the decorator I get the following error message:

```
>>> xy(1, 2) + xy(3, 4)  # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'xy' and 'xy'
>>> xy(1, 2).addition(xy(3, 4))  # But this works nicely
```

It looks like the `__add__` method is not present in `xy` objects:

```
>>> xy(1, 2).__add__  # AttributeError: 'xy' object has no attribute '__add__'
```

But the method is present in the class:

```
>>> xy.__add__  # <function __main__.xy.__add__>
```

What is numba doing to the `__add__` method during instantiation? Is there another way to enable operators for jitted classes so that I can write `xy(1, 2) + xy(3, 4)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently (as of numba version `0.33`) operator overloading on jitclasses is not supported, open issue here:
https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/1606#issuecomment-284552746

I don't know the exact internals, but it is likely the method is simply being discarded.  Note that when you instantiate at a `jitclass` you are not directly instantiating the python class but instead are getting a wrapper around the low-level numba type.

```
v = xy(1, 2)

v
Out[8]: <numba.jitclass.boxing.xy at 0x2e700274950>

v._numba_type_
Out[9]: instance.jitclass.xy#2e77d394438<x:float64,y:float64>
```